# Do unused ES6 modules affect performance?

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-6, compilation

I know for a fact that unused Java/.NET imports won't affect performance. 
But I also know that implementations of `require()` (used to?) simply pull and concatenate the entire required module/file at compile time, and that the `import` statement is sort of an evolution of that. Is it actually different? Will forgetting a very big unused ES6 module in the import list affect my app's performance?

Comment: That depends on what build system you use.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: A bigger question would be why you have unused imports and why aren't you getting rid of them?

Comment: Not having unused imports in the first place would be a better approach, a good linting editor will point these out for you.

Comment: I am! Like crazy! I want to know how crazily I should hunt them. Are they the equivalent of having the entire JS of the module in my file, or are they the equivalent of Java's FQN resolution?

Comment: @iuliu.net import support in the browsers is just starting to come into existence, so most likely you're using a tool like Webpack to traverse the import statements at compile time and produce a bundle of code. What that bundle includes depends on how you've set things up, but generally if you have a reference to another file (ie, an import statement), that file will be included.

Comment: `I should hunt them.`, then don't, get your editor to hunt them.  Or you could even get your build system to hunt them, look at EsLint.  You shouldn't really be writing in Javascript without a Linter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will definitely affect performance, especially if you have non-exported code that does something non-trivial in the module or the module imports other modules. The first time you import a module it will be executed once (and only once). According to the spec:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-module-records

> Do nothing if this module has already been evaluated. Otherwise,
>   transitively evaluate all module dependences of this module and then
>   evaluate this module

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly - it sounds like the unused module has NO effect on performance PROVIDED THAT you imported it and used in any other module, because it will need to be evaluated anyway, but it won't be evaluated more than once regardless of number of imports?

Comment: For example, you can have modules that build caches or start background processes at the time of evaluation. Most of the time classes are just exported but you never know how someone else designed the module