# How significant are unused imports?

Tags: javascript, performance, import

I have multiple screens in my React Native app and some of them have imports copied from another screen, but which are not used on this new screen. Is this a significant hit on performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Worth removing unused imports in big codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715895/worth-removing-unused-imports-in-big-codebase)