# React Native: Does having un-used imports affect performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, import

I'm working on an existing React Native app that has a lot of imports that aren't used. I'm wondering if it's worth combing through and removing all un-used imports. Does leaving them there affect performance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Worth removing unused imports in big codebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715895/worth-removing-unused-imports-in-big-codebase)

Answer (score 0):

even i used to think the same before. but after a lot of concerns mentioned by my seniors , i actually got to know that yes. it matters a lot.

You can add this extension to check the import cost for each file or external library .

Its always better to remove unnecassary imports . I found a great shortcut in mac . option+shift+o it deletes all the unused imports

[image]